# I want to add social share buttons in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, social-buttons

Can anyone guide me how can i add social share buttons in Magento 2 ?

Comment: Where do you want to place share buttons and what do you want to share, like website or product or category?

Comment: add your share buttons code in a BLOCK and call that block wherever you want to show them

Answer (score 1):

If you want to install extension which are easy to implement then prefer below url it is working

https://marketplace.magento.com/magebuzz-socialshare.html

If you want to do custom code

Refer:-https://www.cloudways.com/blog/add-social-share-buttons-magento-2/

Answer (score 0):

First, configure and register the custom module:

For configuration, create module.xml file in app/code/Magenticians/Mymodule/etc:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
            <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
            <module name="Magenticians_Mymodule" setup_version="1.0.0"></module>
</config>
```

For registration, create registration.php in app/code/Magenticians/Mymodule:

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
   \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
   'Magenticians_Mymodule',
   __DIR__
);
```

**Override Add to cart file:**

Copy addtocart.phtml file from  vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view and paste it to app/code/Magenticians/Mymodule/view/frontend/templates/catalog/product/view.

Then create catalog_product_view.xml file in app/code/Magenticians/Mymodule/view/frontend/layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
  <body>
       <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart">
           <action method="setTemplate">
               <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Magenticians_Mymodule::catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml</argument>
           </action>
       </referenceBlock>
   </body>
</page>
```

Now go to [Facebook for Developers](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button) and [Twitter](https://publish.twitter.com/) where you can get their codes which you have to add to your add to cart file.